# How to select rows from DataTable based on Index / Row Number?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, indexing, criteria

I have a `DataTable`. I want to select the rows based on the `Index`/`Row Number` of the rows in `DataTable`.

Suppose below is the `DataTable`:

```
----------------    ---------------
| ID   | Name  |    | Index/RowNo |
----------------    ---------------
| A001 | John  |    |      1      |
| A002 | Foo   |    |      2      |
| A003 | Rambo |    |      3      |
| A004 | Andy  |    |      4      |
| ...  | ...   |    |      5      |
----------------    ---------------
```

Now, i want to select the Rows from above shown `DataTable` using criteria say for example `Index > 2`, In that case First entry at Index 1, `A001 | John`, will not become part of the resultant `DataTable`. How can i do it efficiently?

Moreover, i want to have my result both in the form of `DataTable` and `Linq` query outcome.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var result = dt.Select("RowNum > 1", "");
```

OR

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where RowNum > 1
             select row;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where((row, index) => index > 1)
                  .CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 8):

> I am trying to do something like this:
>
> ```
> var result = dt.Select("RowNum > 1", "");
> ```

You can use [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) even with a `DataTable` since it is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> allButFirst = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(1);
```

get a new `DataTable` with:

```
DataTable tblAllButFirst = allButFirst.CopyToDataTable();
```

If your next question is how you can take only rows with given indices:

```
var allowedIndices = new[]{ 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
DataTable tblAllowedRows = table.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where((r, i) => allowedIndices.Contains(i))
                                .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: +1 What could be faster, than skipping first item and simply returning all remaining items